# How to use invert match in awk along with other patterns

Tags: linux, awk, sed

How to use invert match with `awk` like `grep -v` , i have below pattern mix of awk, sed, grep and sort.

Is there a pure awk or sed way to do the below..

```
$ awk '/status=sent/{print $1,$2,$7,$8|"sort -u"}' /var/log/maillog-20150308 |sed 's/to=<//g' | sed 's/>,//g' | grep -v "relay=local"
```

Sample log..

```
Mar 15 09:00:12 testhost postfix/local[11995]: 7245441DF1: to=<user@smtp.tr-dub01.tr.com>, relay=local, delay=0.02, delays=0/0/0/0.02, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to file: /dev/null)
Mar 15 09:00:12 testhost postfix/local[11995]: 7245441DF1: to=<user@smtp.tr-dub02.tr.com>, relay=mysmtp.com, delay=0.02, delays=0/0/0/0.02, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to file: /dev/null)
```

Current and desired Output:

```
$ awk '/status=sent/{print $1,$2,$7,$8|"sort -u"}' /tmp/test |sed 's/to=<//g' | sed 's/>,//g' | grep -v "relay=local"
Mar 15 user@smtp.tr-dub02.tr.com relay=mysmtp.com,
Mar 7 testUser@example.com orig_nxp41641@smtp.rawat.example.com
```

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: @Cyrus, updated the post with samples and desired, thnx a lot for visiting on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way of doing it:

```
$ awk '
$12=="status=sent" && $8!="relay=local," {  # process only matching records
    gsub(/^to=<|>,$/,"",$7)                 # tune that $7
    b=$1 OFS $2 OFS $7 OFS $8               # buffer output record for
    if(!a[b]++)                             # ... uniq record 
        print b                             # ... output
}' file
```

Output with given sample data:

```
Mar 15 user@smtp.tr-dub02.tr.com relay=mysmtp.com,
```

Updated with a one-liner version:

```
$ awk '$12=="status=sent"&&$8!="relay=local,"{gsub(/^to=<|>,$/,"",$7);b=$1 OFS $2 OFS $7 OFS $8;if(!a[b]++)print b}' file
```

Comment: Thanks @James, can it be converted to one line.